# Where do I setup a custom UITableViewCell's subviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm using a Storyboard with a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass. I do my typical initialization things in `initWithCoder`, but where do I construct the frames of the cell's subviews? (I know I could do this in the Storyboard, but say I want to do it in code.)

Should I be doing it in `initWithCoder`? I thought you weren't supposed to do view related things in the initializer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the following method:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
```

However, you should not call this method directly. If you want to force a layout update, call the `setNeedsLayout` method instead to do so prior to the next drawing update. If you want to update the layout of your views immediately, call the `layoutIfNeeded` method.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever I use Storyboards and there is a need to layout sub-views in a custom UITableViewCell subclass, I use the `initWithStyle` method to add subviews to the `contentView` of the cell, like so -

`[self.contentView addSubview:customButton];`

If you haven't referred to [Apple's table view cell documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html), I suggest you should have a look.

Comment: Subviews will be removed on each layout pass if they're added in the initializer.